# Is it possible in Android to add exceptions to Do Not Disturb for certain apps?

Tags: java, android

I mean say I want to create a system app that toggles Do Not Disturb but makes exceptions for any apps the user desires. This for example would allow a user to block all notifications except from certain apps. Is there a way to achieve this in Android? I know you can use the `NotificationManager` class to make exceptions for certain types of disturbances, but I need exceptions to be for package names instead.

Comment: you can not disable other applications notifications. you can just receive them or you can open the app notifications setting to let users cancel them.

Comment: I don't mean disable other apps' notifications, I just mean allow them to override Do Not Disturb.